# How to retrieve n number of rows from DataTable through for loop

Tags: c#

Hi i am facing problem while i am trying to retrieve the data from the database which encrypted, during sending data into database.

Now i want decrypted the data during retrieving time and view it in Data grid-view control.
I have decrpyt function as well which is like decrypted(string Decrypting);. But the issue is i am not able to implement the Loop and implement the decrypted function so that i can get actual data into data Grid-View control. Please help me that will be appreciated.

```
  public void SelectData() {   try    {  DataTable dt = new SQLTool().ExecuteOutput("Select * from CustomerTable where Date  between '" + TextBox1.Text.Trim() + "' and '" + TextBox2.Text.Trim() + "'");       

        gvCustomerDetails.DataSource = dt;           

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }

    //Button2.Enabled = true;
    //Button1.Enabled = false;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through every record and place at the smae spot

Just Try Adding

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    dt.Rows[i][j] = decrypted(dt.Rows[i][j].ToString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can decrypt the data in dt and update it before assigning dt as a DataSource to the data grid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
   {
       dt.Rows[i]["column_name"] = YourDecriptionFunction(dt.Rows[i]["column_name"].ToString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
dt.Rows.AsEnumerable().ForEach(x => dt.Columns.ToList().ForEach(y => dt.Rows[x][y] = decryptedFunction(dt.Rows[x][y].ToString())))
```

**Is untested, but it's suppose to go through every row and columns decrypting and storing in the same row, column